# cURL does not briing content of url

Tags: php, curl

My php script worked up until yesterday.

Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);



curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if (!$html) {
    die("something's wrong!");
}
```

Now I see the `something's wrong! message`.

the url is running because I can load the page in my browser,

If I try from a terminal the `curl www....` I get the `0HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` response but I have specified the FOLLOWLOCATION flag.

How to debug it? What am I missing?

Comment: What does the `location` header look like? What is the URI you are trying to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Martin

Comment: Still the same.. Might it be that the server hass blocked my address?

Answer (score 0):

Use the verbose mode to trace the calls.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
```

It can happen that the site is returning the 301 status but not providing any link into `Location:` response, and doing the redirection using Javascript or Meta refresh.

Comment: Still the same. is there a possibility that they have blocked my IP? It worked until 3 days ago.

Comment: Server didn't block you. Cause the url works with your `curl` from commandline. What did the verbose mode return you? I mean the http response that you got for the link.

Comment: But in the command line I do not run it from the same IP. The php script is on my server, command line is my home IP.

Comment: IF the site blocked your server then it should show on the verbose output as I posted earlier. Something like 'connect failed'.

Comment: It seems that the site has blocked my server. If I run the same php on  a localhost, I can see the response. Therefore should I suppose that my server is blocked?